Best Practices for allowing analytics access for Third-Party SEO/SEM vendors
I am managing a large multi-tenant web property, where each tenant has some autonomy over whom they partner with for analytics. We need to retain full control over our analytics (GTM/GA) and also need full visibility into all analytics data for the entire property.
What is the best practice for allowing third parties to have some autonomy for tracking things like campaigns or CRO changes, without allowing them to "see" analytics data for any of the other tenants (subdirectories).
Is there a way to grant a third party account access to GTM and GA, limited to only a subdirectory (or set of subdirectories)?
What are the best practices for working with third party vendors when it comes to a multi-tenant property segmented by subdirectory (example.com/site-1, example.come/site-2)?

I assume from the question (and past questions) that you have one GTM/GA property for the multi-tenant site. If this is correct, it will be rather difficult to restrict your vendors from seeing parts of the site that they are not supposed to impact.
For GTM, you will need to act as a final approver to ensure the vendor is only dropping tags on their respective sections. You can do this by making sure the vendors do not have publish rights to the container. This means a lot more overhead in the container owner (probably you) in that you will need to vet each new change.
For Google Analytics, the easiest thing I can see is creating separate reports for each vendor specific to their tenant and data needs via Looker. Give them access to the reports and you won't need to worry about what they can see because you can filter down to their needs only. Until Google adds back views into GA4, you have to piece together something that works.
